# Как дождаться загрузки YouTube selenium + phantom.js (c#)?

Tags: c#, парсер, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

Пытаюсь спарсить список видео с youtube, захожу на страницу при помощи Selenium + Phantom.js

```
IWebDriver webDriver = new PhantomJSDriver();
            webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(@"https://www.youtube.com");
            try
            {
                WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
                IWebElement firstResult = wait.Until(e => e.FindElement(By.CssSelector("ytd-rich-item-renderer")));
                Console.WriteLine(firstResult.Text);
            } catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                Console.WriteLine(webDriver.PageSource);
            }
            
            Console.ReadLine();
```

В коде ожидаю загрузки страницы и появления элемента `ytd-rich-item-renderer`, но элемент не находит

И в консоль выводится исходный код страницы до выполнения всех скриптов, в чем может быть проблема? Почему за 30 секунд страница полностью не загрузилась?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На скрине видно, что страница еще не прогрузилась и нет нужного элемента.

Также вставлял полученный исходный код, что выдало в консоли в редактор кода, и так же не нашел нужного элемента, страница 100% не успевает выполнить скрипты, но не понятно по какой причине

UPD: Еще раз хочу обратить внимание, что селениум ждет таймаут, который указан, но элемент все равно не появляется. После истечения таймаута, когда вывожу страницу, вижу исходный код, до срабатывания скриптов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7312740/5752652

Comment: @AK посмотрите мой исходный код, там то же самое, что в ответе, который Вы дали. Selenium ждет 30 секунд, но все равно не находит нужный элемент

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется селектор неправильно указан.

У тебя ни точки ни решетки не стоит в селекторе. То есть оно ищет буквально ТЭГ(и то я не уверен что он именно так ищется), а не значение АТРИБУТА (класса в данном случае).

Попробуй искать по селекторах

```
By.CssSelector(".ytd-rich-item-renderer")
```

или

```
By.XpathSelector(".//ytd-rich-item-renderer")
```

лично я по обоим селекторам нахожу необходимые элементы через плагин браузера. Вполне возможно что это какие-то ограничения селекторов самого селениума.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я пробовал различные селекторы, посмотрите на скрин внизу, там есть такие элементы

Comment: Я не знаю какие селекторы ты пробовал. Так же и на скриншоте не видно что ты пробовал. Если пробовал разные варианты - пиши их. К сожалению мне не завезли способностей медиума или оракула)

Comment: написал пару селекторов которые должны сработать